# How to add remotely an app in site content using C# or PowerShell (SharePoint 2016)

Tags: development, catalog

How can I remotely add in site content an app already deployed in the App Catalog ?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know about any official way how to do it with code/PowerShell, but this could help https://blog.robgarrett.com/2016/05/09/deploying-a-sharepoint-add-in-from-the-catalog-via-powershell/